# How Detect Any Url in Contect by Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to Detect the any Url(with or without http,https,www...) in the text by regex on c#
In any case, I want to Detect the domain name or url

Please help me

Sample :

```
google.com
http://google.com
http://www.gooogle.com
gooogle . com
```

sample regex :

```
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]"

([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

> The above code examples can't detect gooogle . com

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
(http\:\/\/)*w*\.*go+gle\s*.\s*com
```

https://regex101.com/r/782DNM/1

Comment: thanks for your help
your regex just detect google.com, google is my sample
my users have own domain and i dont want use own domain in content so i need detect domain or url